# Recovering MySQL 5.7 tables in MariaDB 10

Tags: mysql, mariadb, restore

I did a very foolish thing... I did not realize installing mariaDB would uninstall MYSQL 5.7 using apt-get. (Using Ubuntu 16.04).

So now I am trying to recover my data.

So far, I have read many guides and tried several things.  I think this has gotten me into bad position, because the advice seems to be very version specific.

My most successful attempt is 1) Fresh install of MaraiDB. 2) copy * files from old sql directory to new. 3) Copy database directory myDatabase/ from old sql directory to new. 3) Run mysql_secure_installation 4) Configure my users, etc. etc.

This works except that I cannot run sql queries.

```
SELECT * FROM myDatabase.tableOne;
```

I get either:

```
SQL Error [1932] [42S02]: (conn:56) Table 'myDatabase.tableOne' doesn't exist in engine
```

OR

```
SQL Error [1146] [42S02]: (conn:56) Table 'myDatabase.tableTwos'
```

It seems that all tables give one of these two errors.

So far, I have read that mysqlcheck can fix this.

If I run

```
/var/lib/mysql$ mysqlcheck myDatabase
myDatabase.tableOne
Error    : Table 'myDatabase.tableOne' doesn't exist in engine
status   : Operation failed
```

I can't find any suggested solutions for fixing this. Although perhaps I went the wrong way from the beginning. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing anything else I would recommend that you backup the old mysql data directory and the configuration file on /etc. So should something go wrong you don't loose your data.

Then I would check what specific MariaDB version of you have installed. As per [MariaDB compatibility chart](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/), you need MariaDB 10.2 to migrate from MySQL 5.7. Once you are sure you have the right version installed, you should refer to the migration doc:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/migrating-to-mariadb/

Alternatively you could uninstall MariaDB and install MySQL again, just check that you are installing the latest 5.7 version available. For this you can download a deb package from the [mysql downloads](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.7.html#downloads) and install it manually or set up the mysql repository: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/

Answer (score 0):

error is showing that, You are using old ibdata file. I would recommend, uninstall mariadb and install mysql back. Then take healthy backup.

And do fresh installation of mariadb and restore backed up data.

Comment: it might be a good idea to create a backup of the entire machine prior to doing any of this.  In my experience, uninstalls of mysql-based products can sometimes remove the data files, too, which might be bad if you don't have a backup.